# Floor and Ceiling Series (I)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove or disprove:

1) $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\lfloor n^2/2 \rfloor}} = \frac{1+\zeta(2)}{2}$$

2) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\lceil\ n^2/2 \rceil}} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2} \tanh(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Comment: You need to sum even and odd terms in separate series

Comment: So, you know the technique. What is the issue, then?

Comment: To see if there are other methods to solve the problem

Comment: Other than computing the resulting series? They have been discussed many times here on MSE.

Comment: I think this seems to be an interesting problem but someone has vote down my question. I can delete it.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000982 and https://oeis.org/A007590

Comment: I am not saying it is not interesting, I am just saying it is an abstract duplicate. Many questions here deal with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}$ and with $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+z^2}$, that are the relevant series. If you are interested in methods of evaluation, just perform a search. Anyway, I have not downvoted your question, but I still see no point in keeping it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the series into even and odd terms. The first one:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\lfloor n^2/2 \rfloor}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2+2n}$$
The second:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\lceil n^2/2 \rceil}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2+2n+1}$$

The first term is simply $\zeta(2)/2$. The second term in the first expression is a simple telescoping sum. The second term of second expression is a bit trickier. I'm trying partial fractions, I'll post when I find an elegant solution.

Comment: The identity $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2+z^2}=\frac{\pi}{4z}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$$ is well-known and proved many times here on MSE. A possible proof comes from considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function.

Comment: Yes, it's well known - I was looking for the easiest proof but as it's been done many times, I don't have to.